# Memory leak(?) after UITextField tapped even once

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

Thank you for reading my question.
(Sorry for my bad English.)
In my code, I found a memory leak on Debug Memory Graph and Instruments (Xcode).

**Here is my code(Swift4.2),**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpUI()
    }

    private func setUpUI(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = .orange
        let textField = myTextField()
            textField.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(textField)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
         self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

class myTextField:UITextField{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
         super.init(frame: frame)
         self.setUpUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setUpUI(){
        self.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 50)
        self.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        self.placeholder = "TEXT"
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension myTextField:UITextFieldDelegate{
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

**When Memory leak**
・Run this code on my **iPhone6(iOS10.1), not iOS simulator**(this memory leak is not found on iOS simulator).
・I found a memory leak after UITextField tapped(show keyboard) even once.
・This memory leak is not removed after edit ended(hide keyboard).
・I use Debug Memory Graph(Xcode) and Instruments(Leak Checks).

I don't know what goes on and how is the best way to solve this problem.
Could anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: delete this line self.delegate = self

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code you have for view controller and text field? There's nothing here that can cause a memory leak

Comment: Yes, this is all code what I have this project (except for Appdelegate). When I run this code on my iPhone with Instruments(Leak Checks) and TextField is tapped, Leack Checks on Instruments are changed to red.

Comment: Similar problem. Seems to be related to making the textfield the first responder with 
textField.becomeFirstResponder OR tap on the text field to bring up the keyboard for me. Is a big jump in memory that I don't get back. I am thinking it is related to the keyboard?